# Ajustar precisión de Decimales en Función

Tags: vb.net, .net

Desarrolle una función que tiene como objetivo calcular el monto a pagar aplicando un interés. Esta recibe 2 parámetros un monto como String de un label y un valor Byte que estable la cantidad de días de interés a calcular.
Llamo a la misma de esta manera

```
tmp = CalculaInteres(LbTotal.Text, 15)' LbTotal.text =574,65

Private Function CalculaInteres(Monto As String, Dias As Byte) As String
    Dim Resul As Double
    Dim Resultado As String

    Resul = (CDbl(Monto))                           ' monto de String a Double
    Resul = (Resul + ((Resul * Dias) / 100))        'calcula el interes y lo suma
    Resultado = FormatNumber(Resul, 2)              'ajusta a 2 decimales       
    ' la funcion me devuelve 660,85
    Return Resultado
End Function
```

El asunto es que si hago la misma operación en una calculadora **574,65 + (574.65 * 15) /100** OBTENGO **660.8475** y no se si es correcto que redondee hacia arriba o sería correcto obtener **660.84** ??

Comment: Tu pregunta es si es correcto redondear hacia arriba o hacia abajo? Ese es un requerimiento funcional que debes definir tú (o que debes revisar en las normas que regulan tu producto, si es el caso).

Comment: Entiendo tu planteo y tienes razon eso lo debere consultar con el que solicito el desarrollo. Ahora no respondes como puedo redondear a 2 digitos sin redondeo.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara, por eso no di una respuesta sino un comentario :)

Answer (score 0):

La funcion formatnumber redondea a dos decimales, si lo que desea es truncar los decimales debe utilizar otra funcion.

la funcion ene este caso para truncar a dos decimales seria:

```
Math.Truncate(Resul * 100) / 100
```

Comment: Eso no me ayuda mucho.. 
Cual otra funcion ? 
Recien empíezo con VB.net

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el siguiente snippet:

```
''' <summary>
''' Trunca un decimal con una determinada precisión pero sin realizar redondeo
''' </summary>
''' <param name="valor">Número decimal que se quiere truncar</param>
''' <param name="decimales">numero de posiciones decimales que se quiere mostrar (sin redondeo)</param>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Shared Function TruncateDecimal(valor As Decimal, decimales As Integer) As Decimal
    Dim stepper As Decimal = Math.Pow(10, decimales)
    Dim tmp As Integer = Math.Truncate(stepper * valor)
    Return tmp / stepper
End Function
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
    Dim foo1 As Decimal = 12.3956
    Debug.Print(TruncateDecimal(foo1, 1))
    Debug.Print(TruncateDecimal(foo1, 2))
    Debug.Print(TruncateDecimal(foo1, 3))
```

Resultado:

```
12,3
12,39
12,395
```

Un saludo.